# add-movie function does not work as intended

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Over a couple of trial and errors, my add-movie function is not seeming to work. It takes in a movie structure and an array. It adds the movie into the array if the array is not full and there are no duplicates.

```
(defstruct movie
  title director year type)

(defun add-movie (movie array)
  (let ((mtitle (movie-title movie)))
    (dotimes i (length array)
        (if (not (equal (aref array i) NIL))
            (let ((atitle (movie-title (aref array i))))
              (if (equal atitle mtitle) (return nil)
                  (setf (aref array i) movie)))
            (progn
              (setf (aref array i) movie)
              (return nil))))))

Trying it out results in error:
CL-USER> (defvar a (make-array 4 :initial-element NIL))
CL-USER> (add-movie (make-movie :title "Titanic" :director "James Cameron" :year 1997 :type "Romance") a)
```

Comment: Look at the [`dotimes`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_dotime.htm) macro docs and compare the example code there with the code you've shown. Are you passing the same arguments in the same shape?

Comment: There's no need to use `DOTIMES` in the first place. Use the built-in `FIND-IF`

Comment: If the movie is already in the array, but there's a NIL before it, NIL will be replaced with the movie and you'll get a duplicate. You need to first search for the title, then if that fails replace the first NIL with the movie.

Comment: Much simpler to use an adjustable array with [`vector-push-extend`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_vec_ps.htm). Starting from `(make-array 1 :adjustable t :fill-pointer 0)` as the empty movie list, your entire function could be written simply as `(unless (find (movie-title movie) array :key #'movie-title :test #'string-equal) (vector-push-extend movie movies))`.

Answer (score 2):

When I enter your function `add-movie` in CLISP I get this error:

```
*** - DOTIMES: I does not match lambda list element
  (SYSTEM::VAR SYSTEM::COUNTFORM &OPTIONAL SYSTEM::RESULTFORM)
```

You want to get the syntax right.

Check the syntax for the macro `dotimes` here: [CLHS: Macro DOTIMES](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_dotime.htm)